# How to suppress "module_attach"/"module_detach" debugger logs

Tags: c++, c, qt, dll, windbg

I have a Qt application that interfaces with DLLs. The UI is dynamic and explicitly loads a DLL (using `LoadLibrary()`), and this DLL then implicitly loads other DLLs.

When running the program without debugging, everything seems fine. But when I attach a debugger (in this case CDB), the standard output is flooded with lines like this :

```
@{module_attach|051D0000| 17|  0|  0|295|051EA40F| 18|C:\Users\XXX\YYY.dll:15|24|28|32|36|40|49|53}@
@{module_detach|051D0000:15}@
```

Where YYY.dll are DLLs loaded by my program. It makes the debug extremely slow, eventually crashing it. The DLL written are often 2 or 3 DLL the program uses, but not always the same (and it's never showing the message for ALL the DLL loaded).

Is it a debugger issue or did I do something wrong ?

Some precision : the Qt app is written in C++ and uses `LoadLibrary()`. The DLLs are written in C and only use implicit loading. Of the 6 DLL that are loaded, one is loaded by the Qt app, the rest implicitly. Only one of the DLL have a DLLMain, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is that really standard output, or are these debug messages? Do you see the same in [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) (might appear even without a debugger attached)?

Comment: *"makes the debug extremely slow, eventually crashing it"* - I doubt it, most likely there is some issue with dll loading / unloading

Comment: @ThomasWeller I use Qt Creator to run and debug, and it shows in the standard application output (where Qt redirects STDOUT and maybe other streams)

Comment: @VTT Well yes, but do you have any idea what kind of issue would cause that ?

Comment: if it crashes then you should debug that, e.g. check the call stack, check that dll does not rely on global (un) initialization or, if it does, that it is performed properly

Comment: "and maybe other streams" - yes, one of them may be the debug view stream. Have you tried DebugView?